# Thinkpad X230 Keyboard Light near camera is not working

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad

I am  using Lenovo ThinkPad X230 the keyboard light is given near camera. I had upgraded windows 10 to new build 1703. It was working fine all of sudden its not powering on using function fn key. I restarted many times. I check with drivers also but same result.

Comment: This light isn’t controlled by drivers. (Or at least it wasn’t on earlier ThinkPads.) It’s probably just broken.

Comment: it was working till last night. I upgraded windows 10 to 1703 build. It seems after that fn Light is not powering on.

Comment: I am not understanding the issue